# Good Word for a Doer of Crossword Puzzles

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm thinking mostly of the cryptic crossword puzzles that appear in the major English newspapers such as the Times and the Guardian.  The person who creates the puzzle is a compiler, the compiler of the crossword puzzle.  What would be a good word for a person who tries to complete the puzzle?   'Taker' doesn't seem quite right.  An example is:  Winston was an enthusiastic ____ of crossword puzzles, especially the one in the Guardian.

Comment: I think "solver" fits best here.

Comment: You may reformulate the sentence: "Winston was a crossword puzzle enthusiast, ..."

Comment: @arbitrarystringofletters Great.  That is perfect.  Can you make it an 'answer" or should I?

Comment: @Elian offers a similar enough answer. If you prefer "solver," I would mark his as the correct response.

Answer (score 7):

He's a...

> [**cruciverbalist**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cruciverbalist/) *- a designer or aficionado of crossword puzzles*  <sub><sup>(dictionary.com/)</sup></sub>

...like me (probably 99.999% of us *solve* crosswords rather than *create* them).

Comment: I voted for it. Using ngram with both "cruciverbalist" and its french equivalent "cruciverbiste", you will notice that the usage of the word is 20 times more frequent in French than in English. I think that a majority of French people know that word. Not sure that it's also the case for English speakers.

Comment: I dunno - I'd assume it's a broccoli-lover at first glance. :-)

Comment: @Graffito: I've been doing the Guardian xword most days for over 40 years, plus I did a fair amount of work on (non-cryptic) xword generator/typesetting software, so I could hardly avoid knowing the word. But I think you're quite right that *cruciverbalist* isn't familiar to most of my compatriots - it's prolly about on a par with, say, *ichthyologist*. Which is odd, considering how highly-developed the puzzle form is in the UK, whereas I never saw a single French xword during the year I lived there, and I've never seen a *cryptic* American version (they're always just vocabulary tests).

Answer (score 1):

Consider, [**crossword solver**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=crossword+solvers&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccrossword%20solvers%3B%2Cc0).

> *Those of us who are avid readers of crime fiction or enthusiastic
>   crossword solvers (sometimes they are the same people)...* [Treacle, Toast and Tweed ... English Word Origins for Language Lovers](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=551mCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT13&lpg=PT13&dq=%22enthusiastic+crossword+solvers%22&source=bl&ots=nZkNlfcLOC&sig=87yi0dc3wwRplndOVknEwXAhqgI&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMIp-jWwbXZyAIVCVUaCh2Rmwpz#v=onepage&q=%22enthusiastic%20crossword%20solvers%22&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

One ***solves*** a crossword puzzle, principally because one solves any puzzle (hence the person is a *solver*).

Unfortunately the only reference to corroborate that is [myriad Google results](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=solve%20crossword)

> Quickly solve your crossword puzzle on a single page | [crosswordsolver.org](http://www.crosswordsolver.org/solve/-ko---)
>   The Universal Crossword Solver uses a massive database of everything to solve crossword puzzles regarding any conceviable [sic] topic. | [crossword-solver.org](http://crossword-solver.org/)